# How to add tabindex=0 to all the inner elements

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility, nvda

I want to add `tabindex` to all the elements(**except parent that wraps**) it that has text, so that I can tab through them and read using screen reader.

```
<div>
 <table class="blue">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><span class="">abc</span></td>
    <td><span class="">def</span></td>
    <td><span class="">ghi</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><span class="">jkl</span></td>
    <td><span class="">lmn</span></td>
    <td><span class="">pqr</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><span class="">stu</span></td>
    <td><span class="">vwx</span></td>
    <td><span class="">yza</span></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

I want to tab to only span, but adding tabindex to each span is tedious. This is just a small example. The sceanrio could be even deeper text within an element and need not just be table format.

Using something like below, would anyway fetch the text for me, but would not read it

```
$('.blue').text();
```

Is there any solution to get all the last tags and add tabindex attr to each of them?

so that I can focus them and read.

Comment: your requirement is not so clear. please provide a small code about html you need out of it.

Comment: What about: `$("span").attr("tabindex", 0);`

Answer (score 2):

You are totally misleading.

**You don't need to and must not add a tabindex to an element to make a screenreader read it.**

Screenreaders can read the text without that, text does not have to be focusable in order to be read. Adding a tabindex will cause accessibility problems (implying that a focusable element won't lead to any action for instance).

Comment: You are right. But how do  we make any data read. for example fight details

Comment: You need to look up the instructions for whichever screenreader software you are using. They all have commands which will read the whole page, or one line at a time, or just the headings, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
$("table.blue span").attr("tabindex", "0");
```

Comment: What if there is `div` instead of `span`? Wont the tabindex get added to parent div also?

Comment: If you replace your `span` by a `div`, it would add `tabindex` to all `div`s, but check my edited answer.